# How to send post to PHP by AJAX and load specific div

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I am building a filter function in ajax and php (I am new to ajax). I have an html input like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="getListSearch(this.value)" name="search_filter">
</form>
```

The current function getListSearch looks like this

```
function getListSearch(filter) {    
    $.ajax({
        method  : "POST",
        url     : "www.example.com/includes/content.php",
        data    : {
            search_filter: filter
        },
        success : function(result) {
            $("#list_content").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

This works but loads the whole result, I only want to show the div with class .list_content from content.php.
I tried the below codes

```
$("#list_content").html($(result).find('.list_content'));
// Tried below also
$("#list_content").load(result + " .list_content");
```

But no success.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: Can you share response (result) of ajax? is it json or plain text?

Comment: depends on the server response, if the response of the server is a complete html markup including the data inside, then you could just `.html(response)` it outright, if it's a json response, then you need to create the markup (if needed), parse the data inside the success block, then use `.html()`

Comment: @RahulN I don't know, I suppose it's plain text but I don't know how to check.

Comment: You can console log it.
```
function getListSearch(filter) {    
    $.ajax({
        method  : "POST",
        url     : "www.example.com/includes/content.php",
        data    : {
            search_filter: filter
        },
        success : function(result) {
           console.log(result);
            $("#list_content").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: please show your `www.example.com/includes/content.php` code.

Comment: @soliver please post your `alert(result);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getListSearch(filter) {    
    $.ajax({
        method  : "POST",
        url     : "www.example.com/includes/content.php",
        data    : {
            search_filter: filter
        },
        success : function(result) {
            var dom_nodes = $($.parseHTML(result));
            $("#list_content").html(dom_nodes.find('.list_content').html());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is `dom_nodes`?

Comment: It's just variable, document object model nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, this worked for me:

```
        function getListSearch(filter) {

        $('#list_content').load('www.example.com/includes/content.php #list_content', {
            search_filter: filter //Post for content.php
        });

    }
```